# How to scale and rotate during single animateWithDuration call

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, uikit

I am animating a `UIView` using the following code.  This works great but how do I get it to animate scale at the same time too, I would ideally like it to scale down to 0 whilst it spins.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(540));
                     recognizer.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];   
                 }];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the `CGAffineTransformConcat` method. Try:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(540)), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0));
                     recognizer.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];   
                 }];
```

Hope that Helps!